# Tool for Scanning for JavaScript Presence?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, grep, web-crawler

Before I start hacking something crazy together, I wanted to check with the community.  Is there currently a tool out there that will crawl through a website and validate that specific javascript is present there?  (My use case is ensuring Google Analytics or Twitter code are present on all pages)

Comment: Looks like a job for `grep -v`… (put differently - if you do not have access to the actual source files, why do you care?)

Comment: Want to ensure clients have GA code on all pages, I don't want access to their boxes and many don't have linux

Answer (score 2):

If you have a linux server with terminal access you could just use grep to find the results.

```
grep  -Lr "sample twitter code" /path/to/directory/*.js
```

-L lists the file name of all files that do not include the code

-r descends into subdirectories

Comment: Voted you up one because this is a potential solution, although in my case I'm checking for clients who won't always have linux servers and also may not give me shell access, so I need a way to crawl a site remotely.  There used to be a tool called SiteScan for this but it's not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) to recursively download the web pages to a local machine, then use `grep` to search for which files do or don't have what you're looking for.